# jQuery Ajax -> How to avoid including every class for one query

Tags: php, ajax, performance

I have several classes in PHP. All separated in files. (class1.php, class2.php)

On my site, I have included them all together, so I can use all of them.

Now, when I use `jQuery Ajax` to get data from the database I have to call another file (like getData.php)

But on this file, I have to include all of the classes (or at least some) again. So every time I want to receive data from the database, it loads all classes again(I think). The problem is, that they're not that small and they are still growing. That's bad, I think.

Is there a way to avoid this? So that I include the classes only once.

Comment: Can you make a dedicated AJAX controller which would only load the necessary classes? PS: read up on dependency injection, it might come of interest to you as it would allow for strict, need-based instantiation of objects

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you mean. The problem is not, that I load every class, even when I need just one class. 
The problem is, that I load this class I need every time, I use Ajax to get data from the database

Comment: You should try a PHP framework to handle that correctly, like Zend or Symphony

Comment: Unfortunately, that's too late.

Comment: How about using an autoloader? You can then simply create new objects as you need them and perhaps automatically load the database class. see [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register)

Comment: This is why APC and memcached were invented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step one: only include the files you need. How? using an autoloader (and a system that can easily determine what file contains which class, like Classname.class.php or something) will help: If you call `new yourClass()` the autoloader will load the file, but only that file.

Now you have a minimal set of files loaded. This set will not get smaller, as you are actually using the files. What you can do is speed stuff up by

1. using APC. Your PHP files get 'cached' and they don't need to be re-parsed again and again.
2. use other forms of cache, like memcached: save certain data in memory so you don't need anything other then your memcache-class loaded (heck, you won't even hit your database anymore for these requests :)  )

Comment: APC sounds good.

I googled it. So if I use APC, it loads the class in the cache. And then I can use the class in another file without re-including it?

So if I have `index.php` where `class1.class.php` is included, I can use this class in say `file2.php` without include the class again? (Provided that I opened `index.php` first, of course)

Comment: you have to understand, APC helps you when you load a lot of stuff, but it isn't a solution to your issue per se. If you include it, the inclusion will be in the code you run. the code just isn't 'compiled' again. so FIRST go with the first thing I said, and that is make sure you only load stuff you need. THEN, if you are still having too much to load, look to other methods. but load when needed, not load everything in case you might need it.

Comment: Okay, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem (if my understanding is correct).
When I use Ajax to get data from the database, it loads and opens a php-file, right? And every time I want new data from the database, it reloads and reopens that php-file. So if you did this 10 times, the class in the php-file is loaded 10 times, which wastes a lot of internet bandwidth.
And that is my problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how this stuff works. If you include a file, it is not loaded as in sent to the user. Say you need 10mb of php to retrieve some sort of data, like "You have 10 msgs". The only thing you sent to the user (bandwith!) is that exact string. No matter how much you need to inlcude. The rest is all done on the server! So it DOES help you, by only loading (on the server) what you need (seriously, your biggest problem is "include everything for when I might need it). APC and Memcache.. just forget about those for now.

Comment: Oh, okay that changes everything :)
Indeed, I did not know that. Thank you for your explanation.